# Adding an option to Post to Twitter from ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application from which I need to post to Twitter.

The requirement is to be able to have a Twitter link, clicking on which the user will be taken to the Twitter login page.
User logs in using Twitter credentials and is then redirected back to the MVC 5 app.
Here there will be a text box for the user to enter the Tweet which will appear on the user's Twitter page.

Here's what I have till now:

1. MVC 5 application
2. Created a Twitter app and have API key, API secret and have the Callback URL

I have read that Twitter now uses key based authentication.
What is this and how does this work in terms of ASP.NET MVC5

What are the next steps after the second step?
What package(s) are needed for integrating Twitter with ASP.NET MVC 5?
Can someone please help or point to a resource that can guide me?

I am new to this and am having a tough time trying to understand this.
I want to document the process so that the next developer doesn't have to go through this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Tweet Sharp (Nuget), but you still need the logged user `accessToken` and `accessTokenSecret` to instantiate the Tweet Sharp service.
Take a look to this great post: 
http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/get-the-twitter-profile-image-using-the-asp-net-identity